# Loop through array of objects, and turn them into LI items in UL

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="dataTable">
    <button onclick="show()">Print data</button>

    <ul id="hcplist">

    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to loop through this

```
let hcpdata = [{ "name": "David", "hcp": 54 }, { "name": "Jack", "hcp": 5 }, { "name": "Hanna", "hcp": 20 }];
```

Make `<li>` items in that loop, and output in a `<ul>` (`hcplist`) without jQuery or other libraries — items like "David 54", "Jack 5", etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Okay, where did you start? Could you [edit] your question and show your attempts, along with an explanation of what exactly doesn’t work in each of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON file in <ul><li> using plain Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199990/convert-json-file-in-ulli-using-plain-javascript) and [Create a <ul> and fill it based on a passed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128700) and [how to append an array inside a ul in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53561590/) and [Never talking about populate a normal view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152659)

Answer (score -1):

```js
let hcpdata = [{ "name": "David", "hcp": 54 }, { "name": "Jack", "hcp": 5 }, { "name": "Hanna", "hcp": 20 }];

function show() {
  let list = document.getElementById("hcplist");
  hcpdata.forEach((d) => {
    let el = "<li>"+ d.name + " " + d.hcp+"</li>";
    list.innerHTML += el;
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="dataTable">
    <button onclick="show()">Print data</button>

    <ul id="hcplist">

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this function

```
  function show()
    {
      let hcpdata = [{ "name": "David", "hcp": 54 }, { "name": "Jack", "hcp": 5 }, { "name": "Hanna", "hcp": 20 }];
    let html='';
    for( let i=0;hecpdata.length;i++){
       html+='<li>'+hecpdata[i].name + ' ' + hecpdata[i].hcp+'</li>'; 
    }
     document.getElementById('hcplist').innerHTML=html;
    }
```